# Javascript calculator string multiple operations

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to complete the Odin project calculator:
https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-calculator

I can get the basic functionality to work, for example 12+7=19 etc.

My problem is getting the following to work:

**Users should be able to string together several operations and get the right answer, with each pair of numbers being evaluated at a time. For example, 12 + 7 - 5 * 3 = should yield 42.**

If I do 12+7, then press =, then 19-5 then press =, etc, it works, but when doing the entire string in one operation doesn't work (unless every number is added or multiplied)

Please can someone point out what is wrong in my program or how you would recommend fixing it:

codepen: https://codepen.io/tear530/pen/mdpNOwL

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="js.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>

    <div class="container1">
        <div class="btn">

            <div class="boxed">
                0
              </div>
              <div class="boxed1">
                0
              </div>



              <div class="row0">

                <button class="bts ac" type="button"onclick=>AC</button>
                <button class="bts ac2" type="button"onclick="deleteLast()">C </button>
                
            </div>

            <div class="row1">

                <button class="bts num" type="button">7</button>
                <button class="bts num" type="button">8 </button>
                <button class="bts num" type="button">9 </button>
                <button class="bts ops" type="button">+ </button>
            </div>

            <div class="row2">
                <button class="bts num" type="button">4 </button>
                <button class="bts num" type="button">5 </button>
                <button class="bts num" type="button">6</button>
                <button class="bts ops"     type="button">- </button>
            </div>
            <div class="row3">
                <button class="bts num" type="button">1 </button>
                <button class="bts num" type="button">2 </button>
                <button class="bts num" type="button">3 </button>
                <button class="bts ops" type="button">x </button>
            </div>

            <div class="row4">

                <button class="bts num zero" type="button">0 </button>
                <button class="bts num" type="button">. </button>
                <button class="bts equ" type="button">= </button>
                <button class="bts ops" type="button">/ </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container1{
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.btn{
    border-style: double;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}



.bts{
    
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.boxed, .boxed1 {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 212px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }


.ac{
      width: 108px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;

  }

.ac2{
    width: 108px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const numButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.num');
const opsButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.ops');
const displayRow = document.querySelector('.boxed1');
const displayRow0 = document.querySelector('.boxed');
const equalButton = document.querySelector('.equ');
const clearAll = document.querySelector('.ac');
let CurrentNum = '';
let previousNum = '';
let operationState = null;

function calculate() {

    let previous = parseFloat(previousNum);
    let current = parseFloat(CurrentNum);
    let result;
    if (operationState == '+') {
        result = previous + current;

    } else if (operationState == '-') {
        result = previous - current;

    } else if (operationState == 'x') {
        result = previous * current;

    } else if (operationState == '/') {
        result = previous / current;

    }

    console.log(previous);
    console.log(current);
    CurrentNum = result;
    previousNum = '';
    operation = null;
    
}

function buttonCont() {

    numButtons.forEach((button) => {

        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (CurrentNum == 0) {
                CurrentNum = '';
            }
            if (button.innerText == "." && CurrentNum.includes(".")) return;
            CurrentNum += (button.innerText);
            refreshDisplay();
            console.log(CurrentNum);
        });
    });

    opsButtons.forEach((button) => {

        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            operationState = (button.innerText);
            operate();
            refreshDisplay();
            
            console.log(operationState);


        });
    });

    equalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculate();
        refreshDisplay();
    });

    clearAll.addEventListener('click', () => {
        CurrentNum = 0;
        previousNum = '';
        operation = null;
        refreshDisplay();
    });


}

function operate() {
    if (CurrentNum == "") return;

    if (previousNum !== "" && operationState !== null) {
        calculate();
    }
    previousNum = CurrentNum + operationState;
    CurrentNum = '';

}

function refreshDisplay() {
    displayRow.textContent = CurrentNum;
    displayRow0.textContent = previousNum;
}


buttonCont();
```

Thank you.

EDIT, thank you @MORÈ, your response helped me figure out the solution, I adjusted what you said and now works:

```
    opsButtons.forEach((button) => {

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        operate();
        operationState = (button.innerText);
        CurrentNum = "";
        refreshDisplay();
        console.log(operationState);
    });
});
```

I also changed the let operationState = null; to =''

The upper display is not correct so I will try to figure that out now.
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

operate function getting called with new operation state. You better calculate first and then change operation state.

```
opsButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        operate();
        operationState = (button.innerText);
        previousNum = CurrentNum + operationState;
        CurrentNum = '';
        refreshDisplay();
        console.log(operationState);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it didn't work exactly, but I modified it an now works, the calculation is correct, the upper display however is incorrect when showing the entered numbers and operations, see my edit above.